# Matrix to list incompatibility with plot function

Tags: r, list, for-loop, matrix

I have a list object of the following format:

```
> str(TEST.Lmm)
List of 16
 $ NofSimulations: num 2
 $ r             : num [1:511] 0.851 1.276 1.702 2.127 2.553 ...
 $ Ltheo         : num [1:511] 10.7 11.4 14.2 23.7 28.3 ...
 $ Lmm           : num [1:511] 27.6 27.6 29.6 58.2 74.5 ...
 $ Lmm.sims      : num [1:511, 1:2] 0 0 14.5 35.5 35.5 ...
 $ Lmm.maxdev    : num [1:3] 266.5 45 25.4
 $ Lmm.intdev2   : num [1:3] 7563233 333376 53004
 $ Lmm.intdev1   : num [1:3] 46093 11597 4472
 $ lower         : num [1:511] 0 0 0 19.3 19.7 ...
 $ upper         : num [1:511] 0 0 14.5 35.5 35.5 ...
 $ k             : num 1
 $ pmaxdev       : num 0.333
 $ pintdev2      : num 0.333
 $ pintdev1      : num 0.333
 $ typeIerror    : num 1
 $ call          : language mtests.Lmm(NofSimulations = 2, k = 1, data.mpp = Ahx[[7]], permutate = TRUE,      rmin = rmin, rmax = rmax)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "mtests.Lmm"
```

I can plot these results without any problem using the following plot command [I am using the functions of a future R-package that has yet been published on CRAN].

```
plot.mtests.Lmm(TEST.Lmm, Plot.zeroline=TRUE, main="", xlim=c(0,rmax), ylim=c(-500,500), xlab=expression(italic(r)), ylab=expression(italic( hat(L)[mm](r)-hat(L)(r))), las=1) #this works fine!
```

The plot function is fairly complex, but what is important to know is that it calls the use of most of the element in the list above (e.g. $ NofSimulations, $r, etc)

I've ran a series of analysis and my results are a matrix of the following format:

```
> Greenland.Lmm
               [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]         [,6]        
NofSimulations 2            2            2            2            2            2           
r              Numeric,511  Numeric,512  Numeric,512  Numeric,512  Numeric,512  Numeric,511 
Ltheo          Numeric,511  Numeric,512  Numeric,512  Numeric,512  Numeric,512  Numeric,511 
Lmm            Numeric,511  Numeric,512  Numeric,512  Numeric,512  Numeric,512  Numeric,511 
Lmm.sims       Numeric,1022 Numeric,1024 Numeric,1024 Numeric,1024 Numeric,1024 Numeric,1022
Lmm.maxdev     Numeric,3    Numeric,3    Numeric,3    Numeric,3    Numeric,3    Numeric,3   
Lmm.intdev2    Numeric,3    Numeric,3    Numeric,3    Numeric,3    Numeric,3    Numeric,3   
Lmm.intdev1    Numeric,3    Numeric,3    Numeric,3    Numeric,3    Numeric,3    Numeric,3   
lower          Numeric,511  Numeric,512  Numeric,512  Numeric,512  Numeric,512  Numeric,511 
upper          Numeric,511  Numeric,512  Numeric,512  Numeric,512  Numeric,512  Numeric,511 
k              1            1            1            1            1            1           
pmaxdev        0.3333333    0.3333333    0.3333333    0.3333333    0.3333333    0.6666667   
pintdev2       0.3333333    0.3333333    0.3333333    0.3333333    0.3333333    1           
pintdev1       0.3333333    0.3333333    0.3333333    0.3333333    0.3333333    0.6666667   
typeIerror     1            1            1            1            1            1           
call           Expression   Expression   Expression   Expression   Expression   Expression
```

I would like to plot each of these separately using the plot command presented earlier. However, when I do the following, I get an error message:

```
# step 1) transform matrix into list
xnew<-lapply(seq_len(ncol(Greenland.Lmm[,1,drop=FALSE])), function(i) Greenland.Lmm[,1,drop=FALSE][,i])

> plot.mtests.Lmm(xnew, Plot.zeroline=TRUE, main="", xlim=c(0,max(Greenland.Lmm[,1]$r)), ylim=c(-500,500), xlab=expression(italic(r)), ylab=expression(italic( hat(L)[mm](r)-hat(L)(r))), las=1)
Plot of r vs L[mm](r)-L(r).
Error in 1:x$NofSimulations : argument of length 0
```

The problem is that I cannot access the data in my list as called by the plot.mtests.Lmm function.

```
> xnew$NofSimulations
NULL
#vs
> xnew[[1]]$NofSimulations
[1] 2
```

So my options are to rather modify the plot.mtests.Lmm function (which I would prefer not) or find a way to work around it... but how? How can I get ride of the extra [[1]]? Also, I would love putting all this into a nice little code (maybe a for loop?) such that I don't have to replicate each steps manually. I would appreciate any ideas of what would be the best approach!

Answer (score 1):

The following should get `xnew$NofSimulations` to return 2 in the example as you gave it (that is, only looking at the first column of `Greenland.Lmm`).

```
xnew<-unlist(lapply(seq_len(ncol(Greenland.Lmm[,1,drop=FALSE])),
  function(i) Greenland.Lmm[,1,drop=FALSE][,i]), recursive = FALSE)
```

However, the example looks like it was tamed down quite a bit from what you'd like to do. If you plan on plotting the data in each column of `Greenland.Lmm` sequentially, I would suggest creating xnew similarly to how you did in your original question

```
xnew<-lapply(seq_len(ncol(Greenland.Lmm)), function(i) Greenland.Lmm[,i])
```

and doing the following:

```
plot.mtests.Lmm(xnew[[1]], Plot.zeroline=TRUE, main="", 
  xlim=c(0,max(xnew[[1]]$r)), ylim=c(-500,500), 
  xlab=expression(italic(r)), 
  ylab=expression(italic( hat(L)[mm](r)-hat(L)(r))), las=1)
```

where you substitute whatever column number you'd like for the list index of `xnew`.

If you want to plot the data in each column in one fell swoop:

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(Greenland.Lmm)),function(x){
  xnew<-Greenland.Lmm[,x]
  plot.mtests.Lmm(xnew, Plot.zeroline=TRUE, main="",
    xlim=c(0,max(xnew$r)), 
    ylim=c(-500,500), xlab=expression(italic(r)), 
    ylab=expression(italic( hat(L)[mm](r)-hat(L)(r))), las=1)
  }
)
```

Do these suggestions get you what you want?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of code there, so I may be way off base, but it looks like you might be able to use `sapply(xnew, "[[", "NofSimulations")` to grab the NofSimulations element out of the list. Once it's in a vector, you could try plotting?

Comment: yes, sorry for all the codes! I was trying to figure out how to explain my problem as clearly as possible... Might have made it more complicated to understand! I'll need to access all the element out of the list, not just NofSimulations. But right now, if I call for xnew$elementofinterest it returns a NULL (only works with xnew[[1]]$elementofinterest. Need to remove the [[]], so I can call the plot function without changing anything in it, but I don't know how to remove these [[]]?

Comment: Try using `sapply` instead of `lapply` when creating `xnew`?

Comment: Thanks @JeffAllen, but that doesn't help, still have the same problem.